# Render .jade with json from ajax GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, pug, render

I have layout for our jQuery, Node, Jade setup to test our api's on a local server.

Using this jQuery call, I am attempting to load the returned JSON into a new .jade page

```
block scripts
script.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#getId').click(function() {
            var projId = document.getElementById('projectId').value;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/api/projects/get/' + document.getElementById('projectId').value,
                statusCode: {
                    200: function (res) {
                        res.render('admin/displayOneProject', {layout:'layout', data:JSON.parse(res)})
                    },
                    500: function(res){
                        alert(JSON.parse(res).status);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

I can confirm that my api is returning the correct data, so I just need that last line to render the new .jade page with the JSON I am sending it. But, when I run this, nothing happens at the end.

Comment: I have resolved this one my own. Getting my client/server code mixed up.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to put a

```
var redraw_view = function () {
your CODE
then 
$div(#of body).change(redraw_view);
```